# The number of ways of filling N cells with a maximum of M filled in any M by M region?

Tags: combinatorics

I wonder if this problem has been solved?

Given an $R\times R$ grid of cells. How many ways can you colour in $P$ cells black so that there is a maximum of (at most) $N$ black cells in any $N\times N$ region? (e.g. if there are 4 or more cells coloured black inside a $3\times 3$ sub-region this is not allowed!)

Call this function $F(P,R)$.

Also the total number of ways of doing this filling an arbitray number of cells $G(R)=\sum\limits_P F(P,R)$.

An approximation would also be acceptable.

By the way, the inspiration for this problem comes from the holographic principle! (The analogy being if there is more than N black cells in an N by N region we say it collapses into a black hole and therefor is not allowed!)

Some obvious results are $F(0,R)=1$, $F(1,R)=R^2$, $F(2,R)=\frac{1}{2}R^2(R^2-1)$ and $F(R+1,R)=0$ from there it gets tricky. But we know $F(P,R)\le\frac{(R^2)!}{P!(R^2-P)!}$ and $G(R)\le 2^{R^2}$

(It might actually be simpler for a torus topology. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are calculations for $F(3,R)$ and $F(4,R)$.

The one for $F(3,R)$ is still relatively straightforward. There are $4$ different ways to select $3$ cells in a $2\times2$ block, and there are $(R-1)^2$ such blocks, so the number of inadmissible configurations is $4(R-1)^2$, while the total number of configurations is $\binom{R^2}3=\frac16R^2(R^2-1)(R^2-2)$, so the number of admissible configurations is

$$
F(3,R)=\frac16(R-1)(R-2)\left(R^4+3R^3+4R^2+6R-12\right)\;,
$$

in agreement with Rob Pratt’s results.

For $F(4,R)$, we need to do a bit of inclusion–exclusion. There are $(R-2)^2$ conditions for the $3\times3$ regions, $2(R-2)(R-3)$ pairs of them overlap horizontally or vertically in $6$ squares, and $2(R-3)^2$ pairs, $4(R-3)^2$ triples and $(R-3)^2$ quadruples of them overlap in $4$ squares. Thus by inclusion–exclusion the number of configurations that are admissible with respect to the $3\times3$ constraints is

$$
\binom{R^2}4-(R-2)^2\binom94+2(R-2)(R-3)\binom64+(2-4+1)(R-3)^2\binom44\;.
$$

From this we need to subtract the number of configurations that violate one of the $2\times2$ constraints but none of the $3\times3$ constraints. These are configurations with three black cells in a $2\times2$ region, with the fourth black cell more than one row or column away. That excludes $3^2=9$ cells if the $2\times2$ region is in the corner, $3\cdot4=12$ cells if it’s on the border and $4^2=16$ cells if it’s in the bulk, and there are again $4$ orientations for the three cells, so the total number of these configurations is

$$
4\left(4(R^2-9)+4(R-3)(R^2-12)+((R-1)^2-4(R-3)-4)(R^2-16)\right)=4(R-3)(R-2)(R^2+3R-6)\;.
$$

Subtracting this from the above yields (for $R\gt1$)

$$
F(4,R)=\frac1{24}(R-2)(R-3)\left(R^6+5R^5+13R^4+35R^3+12R^2+42R-756\right)\;,
$$

also in agreement with Rob Pratt’s results.

This of course doesn’t make much progress towards finding the asymptotic growth of $G(R)$. For that purpose, we should start from the other end. The first issue to resolve is whether $G(R)$ is asymptotically dominated by $F(R,R)$. For $S\lt R$ we have

$$
F(S,R)\le\binom{R^2}{R-1}=\binom{R^2}R\frac R{R^2-R+1}\sim\binom{R^2}R\frac1R\;,
$$

so if we can find the asymptotic growth of $F(R,R)$ and it turns out to be proportional to $\binom{R^2}R$ despite the constraints, then that would also yield the asymptotic growth of $G(R)$.

To this end, let’s introduce the constraints for $F(R,R)$ successively. Without constraints, we have $\binom{R^2}R$ configurations. Now introduce the constraints for the $(R-1)\times(R-1)$ regions. There are $4$ of these constraints, and each is violated if the black cells are restricted to $(R-1)^2$ cells. $4$ pairs of the constraints overlap in $(R-1)(R-2)$ cells, and $2$ pairs, $4$ triples and $1$ quadruple overlap in $(R-2)^2$ cells, so by inclusion–exclusion the number of configurations that satisfy all these constraints is

$$
\binom{R^2}R-4\binom{(R-1)^2}R+4\binom{(R-2)(R-1)}R+(2-4+1)\binom{(R-2)^2}R\;.
$$

To find the asymptotic behaviour of this count, we need the asymptotic behaviour of $\binom{n+\Delta}k$ when $k\Delta$ is of the order of $n$. From Stirling’s approximation we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\log\binom{n+\Delta}k-\log\binom nk
&=&
\frac12\left(\log(n+\Delta)+\log(n-k)-\log n-\log(n+\Delta-k)\right)
\\
&&
{}+(n+\Delta)\log(n+\Delta)-(n+\Delta-k)\log(n+\Delta-k)
\\[5pt]
&&
{}-n\log n+(n-k)\log(n-k)+O(1)
\\[5pt]
&=&
\frac{k\Delta}n+O\left(\frac kn\right)+O\left(\frac\Delta n\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Thus, the count is asymptotic to

$$
\left(1-4\mathrm e^{-2}+4\mathrm e^{-3}-\mathrm e^{-4}\right)\binom{R^2}R\approx0.639\binom{R^2}R\;.
$$

This calculation rapidly becomes more complicated if we successively introduce the remaining constraints, but when I find the time I’ll try to code it and see whether the result remains proportional to $\binom{R^2}R$ and whether the factor of proportionality seems to converge.

---

*Update:*

[Here’s Java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/605e13b9cc813ca436508061cc6aa68f) that performs the inclusion–exclusion calculation for successive constraints. The asymptotic count when we include the constraints for the $(R-2)\times(R-2)$ regions is

$$
\left(1-4\mathrm e^{-2}+4\mathrm e^{-3}-13\mathrm e^{-4}+20\mathrm e^{-5}-2\mathrm e^{-6}-4\mathrm e^{-7}\right)\binom{R^2}R\approx0.546\binom{R^2}R\;,
$$

and with the $(R-3)\times(R-3)$ regions included it is

$$
\left(1-4\mathrm e^{-2}+4\mathrm e^{-3}-13\mathrm e^{-4}+20\mathrm e^{-5}-46\mathrm e^{-6}+78\mathrm e^{-7}-6\mathrm e^{-8}\\+4\mathrm e^{-9}-\frac{51}2\mathrm e^{-10}-4\mathrm e^{-11}-\mathrm e^{-12}\right)\binom{R^2}R\approx0.509\binom{R^2}R\;.
$$

I’ve confirmed these results with simulations. Unfortunately it’s not feasible to do the calculation with further constraints included; the last one already took half a day on my laptop. The simulations suggest that the factor converges exponentially to roughly $0.46$ in the limit of including all constraints.

Comment: Nice work. Seems like this might generalise to some self recursive equation but probably very complicated! Kind of reminds me of the partitions problem - easy to state but hard to calculate!

Comment: @zooby: I added a first bit of asymptotic analysis.

Comment: @zooby: A further update; more to follow :-)

Comment: @zooby: I've added the result with the constraints for the $(R-3)\times(R-3)$ regions included.

Comment: You've done a lot of work! I'm not sure I'm entirely convinced with the argument though... would the same argument lead to the $2^{R^2}$ without any constraints? It's a fun problem though right? :)

Comment: @zooby: It is a fun problem, yes, and the result seems to be interesting. I don't quite understand your question. How would an inclusion–exclusion argument lead to $2^{R^2}$? That's just the basic count of all possible configurations of black cells – you don't need an inclusion–exclusion argument for that, and I don't see how you could make one. What does that have to do with my calculation?

Comment: I'm saying would your argument lead to the correct result of $2^{R^2}$ if nothing was excluded? Just as a check.

Comment: @zooby: I get the impression that you don't understand the argument. The baseline from which it starts is the constraint that the entire grid of $R\times R$ cells contains at most $R$ black cells, which can be arranged in $\binom{R^2}R$ ways. There's no way how this argument could lead to the full count of $2^{R^2}$ without restrictions, and I don't see why you consider this a meaningful "check". You wrote yourself in the question that $F(R+1,R)=0$ is an "obvious result", so I don't understand why you see a need to "check" an approach that starts from there.

Comment: I'll reread your answer. I'm getting confused because the largest term in a binomial expansion is $(R,R/2)$ and yet all the terms still sum to $2^R$ so it's not constrained by the largest term. But I probably missed something in your argument.

Comment: @zooby: I've been working on this some more. I believe there's actually a further factor of $\mathrm e^{-6}$ from the $2\times2$ constraints. It's really quite an interesting problem. I'll hopefully be posting an update soon with a derivation of that factor and some full simulations to back up the calculations.

Comment: I feel like you almost have a something that could be submitted to a math journal.

Answer (score 2):

Here are values of $F(P,R)$ for $P\le R\le 7$:
\begin{matrix}
P\backslash R &1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 &7\\
\hline
0 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 \\
1 &1 &4 &9 &16 &25 &36 &49 \\
2   &&6 &36 &120 &300 &630 &1176 \\
3   &&&68 &524 &2236 &7040 &18280 \\
4     &&&&1199 &10876 &54936 &204190 \\
5       &&&&&29586 &298980 &1702140 \\
6         &&&&&&952290 &10347740 \\
7         &&&&&&& 38064566 \\
\end{matrix}
So the values of $G(R)$ are:
\begin{matrix}
R &1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 &7 \\
\hline
G(R) &2 &11 &114 &1860 &43024 &1313913 &50338142 \\
\end{matrix}

Comment: That's cool. I assume you worked these out with a computer program by brute force? I wonder how $G(R)$ increases. Just from these it seems to be going something like $2^{n^2/2}$ but it's hard to tell. I think maybe there is no simple form.

Comment: In the encycopedia of integer sequences the closest sequence I found was A181168 which begins 2, 11, 114, 1892. Interesting.

Comment: I used a constraint programming solver.

Comment: Which one, if you don't mind me asking? I would like to teach myself more how to program with them.

Comment: The [CLP solver](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=ormpug&docsetTarget=ormpug_clpsolver_toc.htm&docsetVersion=15.1&locale=en) in SAS.